# Filter an array<objects> by two other array<strings>

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic2

i have a short question:

I want to filter an array of objects by two arrays of strings.

My Array looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 12345,
    "title": "Some title",
    "contains": [
      {
        "slug": "fish",
        "name": "Fish"
      }, {
        "slug": "soy", // search term, like a id
        "name": "Soy"
      } 
    ], "complexity": [
      {
        "slug": 4, // search term, like a id
        "name": "hard"
      }, {
}],..
      },

{...}
```

and that are my two arrays:

```
// recipes should not contain this ingredients
let excludedIngredientsArray = Array<string> = ["soy", "fish"]; 

// recipes should not contain this complexities
let excludedComplexityArray = Array<string> = [1, 2];
```

Now i want to filter the recipes by these two arrays and want to remove all recipes which contain the excluded terms

Whats the best way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

**edit:**

recipeArray looks like this:

```
interface recipeArray {
    reciepe: Array<{
        name: string,
        contains: Array<{slug: string, name: string}> //Ingredients array
        complexity: Array<{slug: string, name: string}> //complexity array
    }>
}
```

Comment: What is the type definition for the first array?

Comment: At the moments its <any>, but i will add this later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your first array is like this:

```
interface Item {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    contains: { slug: string; name: string }[],
    complexity: { slug: number; name: string }
}

let data: Item[];
```

Then you can have your desired filtered array like so:

```
let excluded = data.filter(item => {
    return item.contains.every(obj => excludedIngredientsArray.indexOf(obj.slug) < 0)
        && excludedComplexityArray.indexOf(item.complexity.slug) < 0;
});
```

Comment: Oh nice, that was easy! Thanks!